# How to click on anchor tag inside table <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to click anchor tag inside table data. I can traverse inside table till this much:

This is part of my HTML:

```
<td class="table-active" scope="row">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"> Confirm </a>
       <br>
    <a href="https://www.gmail.com"> Reject </a>
</td>
```

And this is what  tried:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE");

x[0].rows[1].cells[7]
```

Click on either confirm link / reject link`enter code here`

Comment: Are you scraping? Or making your own? Maybe it'll be easier to simply navigate to the URL rather than clicking on a link to it.

Comment: yes scraping  @IvanRubinson

Comment: Which tech do u use for scraping? Puppeteer?

Comment: `const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('table a'); console.log(anchors);`

Comment: Well, it seems you know about `getElementsByTagName`, so combine the ideas: `x[0].rows[1].cells[7].getElementsByTagName("A")[0].click()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using ES6 or any modern features of JS.

But to get you started and to create a click event for each anchor tag do the following:

```
var table = document.querySelector("table");

for(var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        console.log(table.rows[i].cells[j]);
        table.rows[i].cells[j].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('clicked');
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean any other alternative? Modern Javascript way?

Comment: i mean trying this way                                                                 x[0].rows[1].cells[7]                                                                                               
 his completely dead end or can be cont.. using Dom

Comment: See my edited code.. if you want to get the Row and cells dynamically on click. See if that works for you.